# Работа с БД из двух приложений

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql

Есть два приложения:

Приложение А - записывает данные полученные с АЦП в БД,

Приложение Б - считывает данные,полученные с АЦП из БД для анализа.

Как сделать так,чтобы приложение Б считывало данные после того, как приложение А закончит записывать данные? Приложение записывает 2003 значения.

БД - postgresql

Язык - С#

Comment: Уважаемый автор, внесите ясность в вопрос в виде кода программ и описания задачи, которую программы решают. Также хотелось бы знать причину наличия двух программ вместо одной.

Comment: Внес поправки. Потому что одно приложение работает с АЦП(оцифровывает сигнал и заносить в БД), а другая анализирует данные. Столкнулся с такой проблемой: 2 приложение считывает данные пока 1 не закончила их запись. 1 приложение заносит массив данных(2003 элемента), а 2 приложение должно работать с последним массивом, который был занесен в БД. То есть получается ,например 1 приложение успела тока записать 1000 элементов, а 2 уже начала считывать , то есть получается что оно считает 1000 новыйх элементов + старые , так не должно быть

Comment: Возможно, такое предложение покажется глупым, но с той информацией, что есть сейчас, могу сказать: запустите второе приложение после первого. Или же опишите подробнее принципы работы Ваших приложений.

Comment: Попытался более подробнее описать проблему

Comment: Наивное решение: добавить к каждому "пакету" записей (те самые 2003) отдельный "идентификатор пакета". И пусть приложение Б считывает только данные с одинаковым идентификатором и наращивает его, когда считало 2003 записи. А приложение А, когда записало 2003 записи, тоже наращивает идентификатор.

Comment: Можно эксклюзивную блокировку на всю таблицу вешать. Если данные вставляются быстро, то никто не заметит.

Comment: Приложения знают о существовании друг друга? Если да, то пусть первое сообщает второму о том, что завершило запись данных. Второе начинает чтение только по получении сигнала.